# How to prevent inconsistency due to simultaneous update and delete events for an entity in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a java spring boot application that uses Elasticsearch to store articles. In micro-service, I listen for update and delete events of article, and based on that I am updating or deleting that article in the elastic search.

**Issue:** However, I'm facing an issue when both an update and a delete event are received for the same article. If the delete event is processed first, the article is correctly deleted from Elasticsearch. However, when the update event is subsequently processed, the article is recreated in Elasticsearch.

Here is the brief code for my update logic

```
private final RestHighLevelClient client;

// Creating index update request
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(index, "article", article.getId()).source(article);
request.versionType(VersionType.EXTERNAL);
request.version(article.getVersion());

// Making ES index call
IndexResponse response = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

In the above code, I am using external versioning and index request for my update event because I receive full entity details in the update event.

Here is the brief code for my delete logic

```
private final RestHighLevelClient client;

// Creating delete request
DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(index, "article", article.getId());

// Making ES delete call
DeleteResponse response = client.delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

One possible solution is to modify my update logic to first check if the article exists.
If it does not exist, I can simply ignore the event. However, if the article is present, I can proceed with the update. But in this approach every time I am making two requests one for GET and then one for updating the article, which can be inefficient.

I have also check for elastic search update API and implemented the below code

```
private final RestHighLevelClient client;

// Creating update request
UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(index, "article", article.getId()).doc(article);
request.versionType(VersionType.EXTERNAL);
request.version(entity.getVersion());

// Making ES update call
UpdateResponse response = client.update(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But this is giving me error as external versioning is not supported by ES update API.

Can anyone please share any solution to solve this issue.